# Stacking two divs with a canvas in each

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

This is massively oversimplified but this is essentially what I have:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="div1" style="width: 581px; height: 643px;">
            <div id="div2" style="position: relative; width: 581px; height: 643px; background-image: url("bg.jpg"); background-size: 100% 100%;">
                <div id="div3" style="position: absolute; width: 581px; height: 643px;">
                    <canvas id="canvas1" width="640" height="960" style="z-index: 0; width: 428.667px; height: 643px; transform: translateX(76.1667px) translateY(0px);"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div id="div4" style="position: absolute; width: 581px; height: 643px;">
                    <canvas id="canvas2" width="640" height="960" style="z-index: 1; width: 428.667px; height: 643px; transform: translateX(76.1667px) translateY(0px);"></canvas>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The elements 'div3' and 'div4' are positioned in the same place - however, the content of 'canvas2' is always being shown above 'canvas1'. I have tried setting the z-index of div3 and div4 but so far to no avail.

What could be happening here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: Please show all CSS for `div2`, `div3`, `div4`, and the canvases. `z-index` has some pretty specific rules when used in conjunction with different CSS attributes.

Comment: Sorted - I moved the z-index into the div CSS rather than the canvas CSS. Also, I'd been getting my z-index the wrong way round!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
ctx1.font = "30px Arial";
ctx1.textAlign = "left";
ctx1.fillText("canvas 1",canvas1.width/2, canvas1.height/2);

var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.font = "30px Arial";
ctx2.textAlign = "right";
ctx2.fillText("canvas 2",canvas2.width/2, canvas2.height/2+60);
```

```css
#div2{
  position: relative; 
  width: 581px; 
  height: 643px; 
  background-color: rgba(255, 0,0,0.5);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#div3{
  position: absolute; 
  width: 581px; 
  height: 643px;;
}

#div4{
  position: absolute; 
  width: 581px; 
  height: 643px;
}

#canvas1{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
  
  z-index: 1; 
  width: 428.667px; 
  height: 643px; 
  transform: translateX(76.1667px) translateY(0px);
  
}

#canvas2{
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
  
  z-index: 0; 
  width: 428.667px; 
  height: 643px;
  transform: translateX(76.1667px) translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="width: 581px; height: 643px;">
            <div id="div2">   
                <div id="div4">
                    <canvas id="canvas2" width="640" height="960"></canvas>
                </div>    
                <div id="div3">
                    <canvas id="canvas1" width="640" height="960"></canvas>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
```

For anyone visiting , I've made a jsFiddle of the solution.

Just verify that all your relevant styling information is within your CSS and that the canvases are declared in your HTML in the order you wish for them to display (or muck around with the CSS to work around this, your choice).